# How do you insert a filter into a graphql query string?

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-appsync

There unfortunately aren't any good examples in the docs of how to pass a variable into a filter as far as I can tell. Here's an example of a query that works in App Sync:

```
 query listPayments {
        listPayments(filter: {residentId: {contains: "some_random_id"}}) {
      items {
        timestamp
        totalAmount
        feeAmount
        transactionId
        paymentTraceId
        paymentReferenceId
        paymentMethodId
      }
    }
 }
```

But I have no idea how to pass that into my function which then interacts with the template string:

```
export const getResidentPayments = async (residentId) => {
  console.log('getting payments...')
  try {
    paymentHistoryResponse = (await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(listPayments, {
        input: {id: residentId}
      }),
    )).data
    console.log('payment history res', paymentHistoryResponse);
    paymentHistoryResponse = JSON.parse(paymentHistoryResponse);
    return paymentHistoryResponse
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('got payment history err', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

const listPayments = ` query listPayments ($residentId: id ) {
  listPayments(filter: {residentId: {contains: $residentId}}) {
    items {
      timestamp
      totalAmount
      feeAmount
      transactionId
      paymentTraceId
      paymentReferenceId
      paymentMethodId
    }
  }
}
`;
```

It would be greatly appreciated if somebody could tell me what I'm doing wrong since it's probably a fairly obvious rookie mistake. I'm shocked that graphql doesn't have a documentation example for this, unless I'm mistaken about that as well.

Answer (score 0):

AppSync builds a lot of the functionality for you. What's the Type Def for `listPayments`?

Did you make a filter input for `listPayments` that takes a field and a string?

Comment: Yes, that's the solution, if you make a filter input for listPayments you can pass different conditions that need to be matched similar to here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=862919&tstart=0